# putting methods in seperate class file from the main class file

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

So I could put all my methods in the same file where my main method is, but personally I hate filling one file full of method that I'll work once on and never come back to. they just seem to get in the way and make it hard reading what I've wrote. So for organizational purposes I've been putting them in separate file and just calling the class and the method.

So my question is: is there any drawback to doing this? an reason why I shouldn't?

Comment: Do you mean that you have two separate classes? One that simply initiates the other? Not really following

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should do that.  Not only that, you should be creating *classes* (and/or interfaces) that encapsulate your design needs; each class would go in its own file, and each class would have methods that relate to the operation of that class.

The classes and their methods define an *API*, which is how the developer interacts with the code.

Comment: there's no draw back to breaking up the methods in to classes?

Comment: @jack, the classes should represent functionality or "things" in your app.  So if you are doing a Rolodex app, you might have an Entry class...

Answer (score 0):

Are all your methods static? Then you can put them in classes at your own taste.
Otherwise, you have combine instance methods into classes according to the logic of the program.

Answer (score 0):

/* Assume that you understand how to properly decompose your program into classes. */

There's no partial class support in Java (unlike C#); all methods of a class should be in the same file. If you keep your classes short and keep few (e.g. one) classes per file, this does not hamper readability.

To remove unnecessary details from sight while working, take a look at folding, that is, visually reducing a block of code to one line. Every sane IDE can fold code blocks and methods. Both emacs and vim have folding modes.

Comment: @Jack: Folding in Eclipse is [seemingly supported since 2004](http://www.vasanth.in/2004/05/04/finally-code-folding-in-eclipse/).